# Skip other hosts if first host is reachable in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am having file consists of Ip address I using below method to to make this inventory for my tasks

**ips.text**

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
```

**main.yml**

```
    - name: Add Instance IP Addresses to temporary inventory groups
      shell: cat ~/ips.text
      register: serverlist
    - debug: msg={{ serverlist.stdout_lines }}
    - name: Add Instance IP Addresses to temporary inventory groups
    add_host
        groups: working_hosts
        hostname: "{{item}}"
      with_items: "{{ serverlist.stdout_lines }}"

- hosts: working_hosts
  become: yes
```

Now I want to make it like if **192.168.0.1** is reachable then it should skip rest of the ips from that file and if **192.168.0.1** is unreachable then only goes to next **192.168.0.2**.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

> Q: *"If 192.168.0.1 is reachable then it should skip the rest of the IPs."*

A: Let's [`wait_for_connection`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_connection_module.html#wait-for-connection-waits-until-remote-system-is-reachable-usable) on all hosts in the [`block`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) and store the connection status in the variable `reachable`. Then use the variable `reachable` to create the group of reachable hosts `reachable` and run new play with the first host from the group `groups.reachable.0`. For example

```yaml
- name: Test reachable hosts
  hosts: working_hosts
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    connection_timeout: "10"
  tasks:
    - block:
        - wait_for_connection:
            timeout: "{{ connection_timeout }}"
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            reachable: false
        - meta: clear_host_errors
        - meta: end_host
    - set_fact:
        reachable: true

    - add_host:
        name: '{{ item }}'
        groups: 'reachable'
      loop: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|json_query('[?value.reachable].key') }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: "{{ groups.reachable.0 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, order your host as you want them in the inventory, set `gather_facts: yes`, and `run_once: yes` of the tasks, and you're good to go:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: ansible_hostname
    run_once: yes
```

Run this playbook on a set of hosts, with the first few in your list powered down, and you will see the task only runs on the first host that is responding.

Another option is similar to what Vladimir suggested, but using the (lack of) results from `gather_facts`:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      first_good_host: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars) | list | json_query(query) | first }}"
    run_once: yes
    delegate_to: localhost
    vars:
      query: "[?ansible_facts!=''].inventory_hostname"

  - debug:
      var: first_good_host
    delegate_to: localhost

  - add_host:
      name: '{{ first_good_host }}'
      groups: 'reachable'
    run_once: yes

- hosts: reachable
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Good luck!