# Select one usable server from inventory

Tags: ansible

I have a group of servers, which may or may not be available at the moment. I want to execute queries against a usable server. I don't know which one to use, though. So I thought I could use an `include...until` construct, but that doesn't work as expected.

Example:

main.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include: get_available_node.yml
      loop:
        - localhost
        - example.com
        - localhost
      loop_control:
        loop_var: domain
      until: available_domain is defined and available_domain|length > 0
    - debug:
        var: available_domain
```

get_available_node.yml

```
---
- get_url:
    url: "http://{{ domain }}"
    dest: /dev/null
    register: url_attempt
  ignore_errors: yes
- set_fact:
    available_domain: "{{ domain }}"
  when: url_attempt.failed == false
```

I thought, my loop should stop as soon as my available_domain var gets set. However, it doesn't.

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [include] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /Volumes/Source Code/playground/stackoverflow/get_available_node.yml for localhost => (item=localhost)
included: /Volumes/Source Code/playground/stackoverflow/get_available_node.yml for localhost => (item=example.com)
included: /Volumes/Source Code/playground/stackoverflow/get_available_node.yml for localhost => (item=localhost)

TASK [Try to curl localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "/dev/null", "elapsed": 0, "gid": 0, "group": "wheel", "mode": "0666", "msg": "Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>", "owner": "root", "size": 0, "state": "file", "uid": 0, "url": "http://localhost"}
...ignoring

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Try to curl example.com] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Try to curl localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "/dev/null", "elapsed": 0, "gid": 0, "group": "wheel", "mode": "0666", "msg": "Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>", "owner": "root", "size": 0, "state": "file", "uid": 0, "url": "http://localhost"}
...ignoring

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "available_domain": "example.com"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=9    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=2
```

At the end, a usable server is in the variable, however, if there are 20 hosts in my original list, it takes a lot of time to loop through them.

Where is my misunderstanding of how the `until` parameter works? Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "I want to execute queries against a usable server" do you mean to say you want to execute tasks against the hosts which are reachable? and ignore which are not reachable?

Comment: I understand that you are looking for "Ansible when host is reachable". Maybe [Skip other hosts if first host is reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60484583/) give some answers.

Comment: No, I don't want to skip the unreachable hosts, I have a service running on all machines, and I only need to fire my tasks against ONE reachable host, they will distribute with each other. That's why my requirement was to find just one random host from inventory which is currently reachable.

Comment: @SipSeb, so you like to run on the first reachable host and skip all others which might be reachable or unreachable.

Comment: Actually, still no. The module I use is `community.general.nomad_job`, and I run it in a play on localhost, but the `host` param of that module wants a host in there. And I need just one random reachable host.

Answer (score 0):

Using `run_once` should work, as long as `setup` is run (ie `gather_facts: true`), because ansible will remove those hosts which can't be reached for Fact Gathering, from the candidate pool for `run_once`, and thus only run on the first "up" host.  for example:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: false
  run_once: true
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - ping:
```

```
$ ansible-playbook -i does,not,exist,localhost, test.yml
```

will run `ping` on only one of 4 hosts only: localhost, the only one that's up

```
PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
does      : ok=0 changed=0 unreachable=1 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
exist     : ok=0 changed=0 unreachable=1 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
localhost : ok=2 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
not       : ok=0 changed=0 unreachable=1 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

(you might have to add `ansible_connection: local` to host_vars/localhost to simulate).  If there are multiple hosts up, `run_once` will only run on the first one from the inventory that's actually up.

Note, if you're doing fact caching, I'm not sure if this will still hold true, because setup might not get run and remove the node from candidate pool.  If you need this, an initial `ping` task through all the servers, followed by the "work" task with `run_once`, might work (untested), with the default `linear` strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I guess I wasn't specific enough with my question. The hosts probably are up, but I don't know if the needed service is up. So yes, I could probably add a "curl localhost" task to check if the service is available on the machine. But then, how do I get the usable host into a variable so I can use it in my task I need it for?