# In Ansible, how to exit with sucess if any host is unreachable (without using ignore_unreachable)

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have the following playbook to get the **first reachable host**.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  ignore_unreachable: yes

  tasks:

  - name: Get the first good host in the group
    vars:
      query: "[?ansible_facts!=''].inventory_hostname"
    set_fact:
      first_good_host: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars) | list | json_query(query) | first }}"
    delegate_to: localhost  
    run_once: yes

  - name: Aggregate the first good host to reachable group
    ansible.builtin.add_host:
      name: '{{ first_good_host }}'
      groups: 'reachable'
    run_once: yes

  - name: print reachable hosts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ groups['reachable'] }}"
```

But this playbooks exists with `4` if there is any unreachable host(s). If I pass `ignore_unreachable: true`, then it exits with `0` but `reachable` also contains the `unreachable` host(s), which is what I don't want to.

I have also tried with `any_errors_fatal` and `max_failure_percentage` but no luck. I don't want to abort/fail on any unreachable host.

How can I deal with exit code `4` without using `ignore_unreachable: true`?

Playbook ref: [Skip other hosts if first host is reachable in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60497331/5685796)

Comment: "_But this playbooks exists with `4` if there is any unreachable host(s). If i pass `ignore_unreachable: true`, then it exits with `0` but `reachable` also contains the unreachable host(s), which is what I don't want to._", can explain in more detail the why? And what do try to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

`ansible_play_hosts` variable already contains only the list of valid reachable hosts of your play. Failed/Unreachable hosts are excluded from this list. Thus, you don't need to create a special custom variable to list only reachable hosts. If you need a list with all hosts including unreachable, you can use `ansible_play_hosts_all`. It contains the list of all the hosts that were targeted by the play.

Comment: Good point about [Special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-ansible_play_hosts) ...

Comment: Thanks, a great TIL for me! I have three hosts group in my `inventory.ini`, which are `control_planes`, `workers` and `etcds`. I used `all` as a placeholder in this example. How can I select `ansible_play_hosts` just for `control_planes` host group?

Comment: The other this is that, I want to get ONLY ONE REACHABLE instead of all actually.

Comment: To get a single host from the list of reachable you can use simple filters like {{ ansible_play_hosts | first }} or {{ ansible_play_hosts | random }}.

Comment: Thanks but this it still exists with 4 If I pass `ignore_unreachable: true`. Also includes unreachable ones. I wonder how @U880D able to made it exit with 0.

Comment: @Dentrax, by setting `ignore_unreachable: true`. That will result into a Return Code of 0 even if there were unreachable hosts.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes. It exists with 0 but also includes unreachable hosts if i try it with `ansible.builtin.add_host`.

Comment: @Dentrax, "_... but also includes unreachable hosts if I try it with `ansible.builtin.add_host`_" the minimal reproducible example in [the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912124/6771046) doesn't contain unreachable hosts according the sample output.

Answer (score 0):

> *If I pass `ignore_unreachable: true`, then it exits with `0` but `reachable` also contains the unreachable host(s), which is what I don't want to.*

With a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  ignore_unreachable: true

  tasks:

  - name: Get the first good host in the group
    set_fact:
      first_good_host: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars) | list | json_query(query) | first }}"
    vars:
      query: "[?ansible_facts!=''].inventory_hostname"
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: yes

  - name: Aggregate the first good host to reachable group
    ansible.builtin.add_host:
      name: '{{ first_good_host }}'
      groups: 'reachable'

- hosts: "{{ groups['reachable'] }}"

  tasks:

  - name: Print reachable hosts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
```

I am not able reproduce that

> *... also contains the unreachable host(s) ...*

The dynamic group `reachable` will only contain the first reachable host resulting into an output of

```yaml
PLAY [all] *****************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************
ok: [test2.example.com]
ok: [test1.example.com]
fatal: [test3.example.com]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false
  msg: 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host test3.example.com port 22: No route to host'
  skip_reason: Host test3.example.com is unreachable
  unreachable: true

TASK [Get the first good host in the group] ********************************************************************
ok: [test1.example.com -> localhost]

TASK [Aggregate the first good host to reachable group] ********************************************************
changed: [test1.example.com]

PLAY [[u'test1.example.com']] **********************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************
ok: [test1.example.com]

TASK [Print reachable hosts] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [test1.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - test1.example.com

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************
test1.example.com: ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0 
test2.example.com: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
test3.example.com: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

and if called via

```bash
ansible-playbook unreachable.yml; echo $?
0
```

Removing the line

```yaml
  ignore_unreachable: true
```

would result into

```bash
ansible-playbook unreachable.yml; echo $?
4
```

Please take note of [the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912103/6771046) and [Playbook execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-execution).

---

> *But this playbooks exists with `4` if there is any unreachable host(s). (annot.: ... and without using `ignore_unreachable: true`)*

Right, that is the expected behavior.

> *How can I deal (annot.: avoid?) with exit code `4` without using `ignore_unreachable: true`?*

You can't avoid it since that Return / Exit Code is provided from the `ansible-playbook` command itself at the very end of the run, not from within the playbook and as far as I understand. Usually I am not linking external content, but in this case you may have a look into [Ansible Exit Codes](https://jwkenney.github.io/ansible-return-codes/).

Furthermore you might also take advantage from [What is the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: Thanks, I have tried exact same playbook on my local but it still exists with 4. My ansible version is `2.13.2`. Same version with the remote hosts.

Comment: But what is question, what do you try to achieve with the exit code of `ansible-playbook unreachable.yml; echo $?`?

Comment: It prints 4 but exits with 0. That's because you append `; echo $?` command.

Comment: No, please see in example [What does `echo $?` do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501129/266568).

Comment: Thanks, but it prints `4`. Playbook does not exits with success.

Comment: But what is question, what do you try to achieve with the exit code of `ansible-playbook unreachable.yml; echo $?`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254933/discussion-between-dentrax-and-u880d).